# No select line in table view exists with added button in ios?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i new in iphone. 
you show this image

[image]

I need code for remove blue select line from table view and only work **BUY Button**.

**Edit**

This cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; work for only style but not work for disable row.

Answer (score 3):

put this line of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: @AnilMetatagg: is it working now?

Comment: wait,@sunny i do try your code.

Comment: Thank You,@sunny My Work is Done.